# Clicking child view and preventing parent view from running dblclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette.js

I have a parent view which has a dblclick event handler bound to it. I also have a view which is a descendant of the parent. This child view has a click event handler bound to it.

Currently, my code works as intended, but looks like this:

```
var ParentView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    events: {
        'dblclick': '_playInStream'
    },

    _playInStream: function () {
        console.log("ParentView _playInStream");
    }
});

var ChildView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    events: {
        'click': '_addToStream',
        'dblclick': '_addToStream'
    },

    _addToStream: _.debounce(function () {
        console.log("ChildView _addToStream");

        //  Don't allow dblclick to bubble up to the list item and cause a play.
        return false;
    }, 100, true)
});
```

The end result of this logic is:

- Single-click on child view runs `_addToStream` (once)
- Double-click on child view runs `_addToStream` (once)
- Double-click on parent view runs `_playInStream` (once)

However, I feel like the way I am expressing this code is overly convoluted, but I also don't see a better way.

The debounce is necessary because double-clicking on ChildView will execute both the click and dblclick event handlers -- but I only want a single event to run.

If I remove the dblclick event handler from the child then a dblclick will propagate up to the parent which is not desireable.

Does anyone see a better way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what seems convoluted to you. It's a simple piece of code, and if you remove anything from it, it will fail to do what you want, as you noted yourself:

- If you remove the `debounce`, the method will be fired 3 times: once for the single click + twice for the double-click. So you need that.
- If you remove the double click handler, then it will be fired in the parent

There is one thing you could "optimize", in the `ChildView` you could make the `dblclick` handler do nothing:

```
var ChildView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    events: {
        'click': '_addToStream',
        'dblclick': function() {}
    },
```

This will work, because the `dblclick` will also trigger `click`, so `_addToStream` will be called. You still cannot remove the `debounce`, because without it the `dblclick` will trigger 2 `click` events.

Finally, the `ChildView` doesn't extend the `ParentView`, maybe that's a typo, and your real intention was this:

```
var ChildView = ParentView.extend({
```

Comment: Well, I'm glad it seems sane to you. Just felt like too much to get a distinct click events, but I'll go with it. Thanks.